# How does this specific routing rule works?

Tags: ip, routing

```
ip rule add from ip.ip.ip.ip table 128
ip route add table 128 to ip.ip.cidr.cidr/range dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via gate.gate.gate.gate
```

Why is table 128 specifically? Why is there a need to specify CIDR range when we already have specified IP? The gate part I understand.

I hope you wont get offended that I did not read 100+ pages manual like you in your time. Thing is this is probably the single and only case ever I encounter routing usecase and I will die in my early 50 without ever returning back to it.

Comment: So 128 is just a convenient name you choose for table? Okay, why there is need for CIDR range?